# How to replace width="512px" or width="512" or width="512.1112233" or width="415.11335577px" with width="{size}" with sed

Tags: sed

There are many files in a directory. It contains `width` with different format.
Between quotes can be digits, float, digits + px or float + px.

For example:
width="512px", width="512", width="512.1112233" or width="415.11335577px"

I'd like to replace them with `width="{size}"`.

I tried it the following but I don't get what I want in some files.

```
sed -i 's/"[0-9]*"/"{size}"/g' ./*.*
```

How can I achieve it using `sed`?

Comment: That's a simpler variant of [this similar question of yours](/q/703995). I'd have expected you'd been able to derive the answer to this one from the answers to that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match zero or more non-`"` characters between `"` an `"`:

```
sed 's/width="[^"]*"/width="{size}"/g'
```